# Risk of Manipulation of Ajax Code by Client

Tags: ajax

As I found, it is possible to ***manipulate*** and ***change*** `Ajax` code in browser console by `client`. For example, `Ajax` wants to call a method and pass `id` to `controller`. As I mentioned above, how we can `secure` our code from ***interference*** by `client`?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security must always be implemented on the server side, because anything you do on the client side can be ignored, overstep, modified, etc very easily. In fact, anyone can use software like Postman to make a completely custom HTML request to any server.

Don't ever rely on any client-side software in terms of security for your server. If you want keep your server safe, then make a safe server.

Comment: How its possible to be ensure that client didn't change parameter manually in Ajax code? For example I have a table of data and there is a button in last cell to call a method with parameter, to delete a row but, client change parameter value. How can I check that in server? thanks

Comment: @HadiMazareei simply you can't, but if you really want to make sure the client only sends you a specific Id you can hash the Id and use the hashed string on the client side instead of integer or GUID.

Comment: @HadiMazareei You can't, if you have some sort of user management, what you can do is check if the current user is allowed to delete that specific row. This way, it doesn't matter what the client changes, they will only be able to delete the rows they are allowed to do so. As I said, you can never rely on the client in terms of security and you can never trust the information that you receive from the client. Never.

Comment: @AliRezaSabouri Hashing the ID has no use at all, if the client can figure out the ID of another row, they will also be able to figure out the hashed version aswell. Nothing you do client-side will ever be safe, it is really easy to just use a different client like Postman and send custom data to your server.

Comment: @Javito I don't know why he wants to do this and I agree that for normal use cases there is no need to do anything on the client side, but hashing is useful sometimes for example for having a captcha we use the same technique, or in our authentication systems we use a hashed signature, etc. so as you answered in normal situations security should be implemented on the server side but there are some scenarios that hashing works perfectly.

Comment: Tank you all. My question is clear. Ajax is not for working with DOM only, it is capable to work with server as well and passing parameter to server is likely. If it is not possible to prohibit client to interfere Ajax code, so how we can control data which has been received from client? Maybe more that **ID** must be send to and receive from client.

Comment: ***Hashing*** is good thing but I should do that for all of my project. Is there a better way? Even if I give ***permission*** to user to delete his own data, it may possible, user wants to ***defame*** my application because of some mistakes which has been done deliberately by user. thanks

Comment: @HadiMazareei This is the authorization responsibility on the server side, there is no way to limit users on the client side. you need to improve your permission system and validations on the server.

Comment: @HadiMazareei You can try making your client-side as clear, robust and user-friendly as possible, and teach users how to use it if possible to minimize the risk of them using it wrong. Nonetheless, it makes no sense trying to implement sofisticated security measures on the client-side. If someone is trying to brake your app, it doesn't matter what you do on your client, the only way to protect it in a reliable way is server-side.